# How to convert .har files to .jmx files?

Tags: jmeter

I am fairly new to Performance testing and need some help!!

I am writing scripts for an internal application that makes a ton of AJAX calls. I am unable to set up a proxy server to use the JMeter recording tool.

The only option was to use the `.har` files and convert them into `.jmx` files. I see there are a few sites which I can use to convert my file, but i need something in house or installed within our system to protect confidential data.

I am not able to find anything that is free and which i can download and install on my machine to do the conversion.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool can do the trick for you, it can:

1. [Import .har file](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Save-And-Load-Traffic/Tasks/ImportExportDefault)
2. [Configure Fiddler to use JMeter the proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ChainToUpstreamProxy) and point it to JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
3. Now you can [resend requests from Session List](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/ResendRequest)

Be aware that real browsers send AJAX requests in parallel, if you want to mimic this behaviour you will need to put the relevant HTTP Request samplers under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. But we are not allowed to configure a proxy due to security reasons, so that will not work for me. The only thing i could use was convert the .HAR file to .JMX file, but i wanted to use a tool that I can install rather than use it for converting online, due to security reasons. I have been trying to add HTTP requests manually to simulate the calls made, and which seems to be working for now, except for a POST call that is erroring out. But it is tedious to create these HTTP requests, enter data in the header manager etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:
https://github.com/Seitenbau/har2JMeter

This is the solution I have found while searching for s similar issue.

Edit:
Found updated repo which works:
https://github.com/bedefaced/har2JMeter